# facebook's share debugger saying that image can't be shared because it exceed 8mb while it's smaller than 500kb

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, sharing

the website i'm working on is on wordpress. for some pages the facebooks share script which i have works and it's taking the right image while for other  they don't work? i have no idea why facebook share debugger  gives the error: Provided og:image, (here it show the image which i want to be shared but it thinks that it's bigger than 8mb while it's smaller than 500kb) could not be downloaded because it exceeded the maximum allowed sized of 8Mb or your server was too slow to respond. so instead of the right image it's picking the next image  because given one it thinks that is too big or the worst case, it's taking white blank so no image on sharing at all!..  i rad all posts at the google but still no luck on fixing. i even tried to upload those images which have no problem on other pages, for example cinedoc-tbilisi.com/?p=945 on this page number it's not sharing the image because debugger thinks that it's too big while it's not! and while
on this page cinedoc-tbilisi.com/?p=1794 . i'll provide my code but i don't think it will have any affection because facebook debugger itself gives the error and not the code: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing can't find the link. my sharing   code itself:` " />

```
<?php /* 
if(is_single()){

    if($_GET["lang"]=="ge"){

        the_title();
    }else{
        the_title();

    }


} */ ?>

" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="
<?php 

    if($_GET["lang"]=="ge"){
        echo "ka_GE";
    }else{
        echo "en_US";
    }

?>
" />
<meta property="og:description"   content="
<?php 
if(is_single()){

    if($_GET["lang"]=="ge"){

        the_field("long_desc_geo");
    }else{
        the_field("long_desc");

    }


} ?>" />
<meta property="og:image"         content="<?php if(is_single()){the_field("image");} ?>" />
<meta property="og:image:width"         content="600" />




<script>

$(document).ready((function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.7";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk')));
</script>



<button class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://www.mywebsite.com/?p=<?=get_the_ID()?>" data-layout="button_count" data-mobile-iframe="true"><a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore " target="_blank" href="#">Share</a></button>`
```

please help!

Comment: Please provide a link to your website so that we can help.

Comment: ok, here are the links http://www.cinedoc-tbilisi.com/?p=945  not sharing....  but here it's sharing http://www.cinedoc-tbilisi.com/?p=2406

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I view the source then this is your 'sharing' image:

http://www.cinedoc-tbilisi.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/cross-the-border-slider-33.jpg

On my computer it takes around 13 (!!) seconds to load. So your size isn't the issue, Facebook just doesn't want to wait that long. Check out any hosting issues you may have, the load time should be down to just a couple of seconds er less. Probably contact your hosting for that.

[image]

Comment: unfortunately i still don't know if it's the case.  i have tried to load pages and check picture load times and kinda the image which each time is take from facebook debugger and the one on which i'm getting error on have the same loading times? i don't know how to fix the problem because service host provider said that they are giving constant speed. can you check if the image i have problems with still slowly downloading and  cinedoc-tbilisi.com/?p=1794 isn't as well? if both have the same speed than perheps it's not the case? sorry for my english

Comment: It takes almost 15 seconds for that image to load on my machine as well. If it is faster for you, then that might be due to factors like geographical location - but from the "rest of the world", it just seems to be too slow. The FB scraper has a time limit of 10 seconds.

Comment: thanks both of  you! I just checked again and all other images are low sized. which makes me to think that i have problem or on wordpress website or on hosting! but i'll find it out! the question is answered, at least now i know what is the reason.  :) thanks guys.